# API request types PATCH and DELETE 404 error typescript

Tags: typescript, api, testing

I'm a tester and I got an exercise to test API requests in typescript. I'm trying to send request type PATCH to server to update some information of existing restaurant(I create it in the code and immediately try to update the data) but every time get 404 error. The same happens when I do DELETE request. I've already tried to execute these requests in Postman. Everything is working fine

These are the tests

```
   it('Edit the existing restaurant', async () => {

        const dataToUpdate = { address: "Holon" };

        //Act
        const updateRestaurantById = await restaurantsAPI.updateRestaurantById(42, dataToUpdate);

        //Assert
        expect(updateRestaurantById.status).to.equal(200);
        expect(updateRestaurantById.success).to.be.true;
    })
   it('Delete existing restaurant', async () => {
        //Act
        const deleteByIdResponse = await restaurantsAPI.deleteRestaurantById(365);

        //Assert
        expect(deleteByIdResponse.success).to.be.true;
        expect(deleteByIdResponse.status).to.equal(200);
    })`
```

And requests

```
  const updateRestaurantById = async (id: number, body: Updates): Promise<ApiResponse<Updates>> => {
    return HttpRequest.networkRequest({ url: baseUrl + 'restaurant', method: HttpRequest.HttpMethod.PATCH, queryParams: { id: id }, body: body });

}
   const deleteRestaurantById = async (id: number): Promise<ApiResponse<null>> => {
    return HttpRequest.networkRequest({ url: baseUrl + 'restaurant', method: HttpRequest.HttpMethod.DELETE, queryParams: { id: id } });
}`
```

Comment: Are you sure, that `baseUrl` is right? And `baseUrl + 'restaurant'` combines in right way

Comment: yes, I've checked it and everything is right from this perspective

Comment: Can you make a screenshot from devtools Network tab of your request and attach it to question?

Comment: I'm sending the request from IDE, not using browser

Comment: Sure, I forgot... The only one reason I see to fail is your `baseUrl + 'restaurant'` isn't correct. Try to replace it with full url like `https://google.com/search`